# PHP, How to write faster query for updating large object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have the following query and it's pretty perfect. It allows me to get points for plotting a graph from my database, for a large range of input time frames and options.

```
$get_net_sql=   "SELECT  nic_name,
        AVG(bytes_sent) as down_speed,
        AVG(bytes_recv) as up_speed,
        unix_timestamp
    FROM (  SELECT  nic_name, bytes_sent, bytes_recv,
                (".
                  $sql_sample_size.
                  "*ROUND(unix_timestamp/". $sql_sample_size. ")
                ) As unix_timestamp
            FROM  tbl_network_stats
            WHERE  timestamp>(NOW() - INTERVAL ". $time. " ". $sql_unit. ")
         ) AS sub_table
    GROUP BY  unix_timestamp, nic_name
    ORDER BY  unix_timestamp, nic_name DESC;";
```

of course, this is a slow query when your dealing with days or weeks of data. So what I want to do is to draw the graph (which is on a canvas) with this query and the update the json object that runs the graphing interval with a much faster query every one second.

I have the joining of working, but I can't find the right faster version of the above query... write now this is what I got:

```
$get_net_sql = "SELECT  nic_name,
        bytes_sent as down_speed,
        bytes_recv as up_speed,
        unix_timestamp
    FROM  tbl_network_stats
    WHERE  unix_timestamp = 
        (  SELECT  unix_timestamp
            FROM  tbl_network_stats
            ORDER BY  unix_timestamp DESC
            LIMIT  1
        )";
```

The real issue I am trying to solve here is that when I'm continuously updating my graph with the first query every one second so it updates live, which is perfect but grabs all new data every time and is slow, my processor is up at 25% due to this and 3 similar queries going on for network and ram trending data. So who would want to watch these fancy charts if they consume 25% of the cpu to do it!

The solution that comes to mind that I am seeking help with, or alternatives, is to run the first query on page load and join it with a faster one every one second.

Thank you Maango, look at what a difference the indexes made (I could have spent a month on this problem, Thank you so much, so obvious yet so buried a solution):[image]

Comment: What are the values on the axes?

Comment: I'm rick james biotch! % vs time, dynamic x axis based on time range selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

First change your subquery to this:

```
(SELECT max(unix_timestamp) FROM tbl_network_stats)
```

That may make some difference, but I don’t have your data to test it with.

Second, add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_network_stats ADD INDEX ux_ts (unix_timestamp);
```

This will speed up any `ORDER BY` or other clauses which require finding values.

Comment: You are the man Manngo! look at the screen shot, the index saved my life! Really man, it would've taken me a month to realize, thank you so much! Now I'm going to try your subquery suggestion and maybe make it even faster... your saying that MAX is likely faster than the ORDER BY clause in the second query?

Comment: @user3656612 I haven’t tested my self, but my guess is that, especially with the data indexed, it should be easier to find the maximum than to sort the whole table. That’s just a guess, and I don’t think it will make a huge difference. BTW, if you’re happy with the answer would you mind accepting it?